# PulseAudio / MPD/ HTTP Streaming Installation Guide

Tags: raspbian

After struggling for some time with installing PulseAudio, and getting MPC/MPD working with HTTP streaming on Raspian I have put together some notes (mainly for my benefit), but would appreciate any feedback from members of the community as to if I have missed anything.

I would class myself as an intermediate user, so I am sure some experts out there could suggest improvements.

I still have a few minor issues which I will document later this week. I will also add more on usage of MPC and streaming.

Kind regards, and thanks in advance for any feedback.

http://caramel.pancakeapps.com/

### Raspberry Pi

#### PulseAudio & MPD/MPC Installation

Initial Installation

Start by entering these commands from the terminal to update your system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now install PulseAudio and the other required packages

```
sudo apt-get install mpd mpc pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-zeroconf mpg321 lame mplayer pavucontrol paprefs
```

Installing mplayer, mpg321 and lame will ensure that the MP3 codecs are setup, and that we can play MP3 files from the command line

At this point it is worth rebooting the system

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Configuring mpd

The configuration file for mpd is stored in `/etc/mpd.conf`

By default mpd will look in `/var/lib/mpd/music` for music files, and in `/var/lib/mpd/playlist` for .M3U playlists

Edit the mpd configuration file with the nano text editor by issuing the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/mpd.conf
```

Change the `music_directory` and `playlist_directory` settings to point to the location where your music files are stored

We also need to tell mpd to use the PulseAudio sound system rather than ALSA.  Add these lines to the end of `/etc/mpd.conf`

```
audio_output {
type "pulse"
name "MPD PulseAudio Output"
}
```

Remember to save the changes to the file when you exit

Issue the following commands to set the correct permissions for the folder

```
sudo chmod -R o+r  (CHECK!)
sudo chmod -R o+r  (CHECK!)
```

For example if you use the default directory you would type

```
sudo chmod -R o+r /var/lib/mpd/music
```

At this point it is worth rebooting the system again

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Configuring PulseAudio

The first step is to edit the PulseAudio configuration file with the nano text editor

```
sudo nano /etc/default/pulseaudio
```

Add the following two entries to the end of the file

```
PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=1
DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=0
```

Step two is to make some changes to another PulseAudio file

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/system.pa
```

Comment out the `load-module module-suspend-on-idle' by adding a '#' to the start of the line

Add the following two entries at the end of the file (Most home networks use '192.168.0.0/24', but it is worth checking with your provider if you have problems

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

The final step is to convert the ALSA configuration libraries to PulseAudio

```
sudo nano /etc/asound.conf
```

Add these entries to the file

```
pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

My Raspberry Pi is connected to our television via and HDMI cable, and I find the by default the sound does not work. To resolve this we need to edit the Raspberry Pi configuration file

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add the following line to select HDMI audio mode

```
hdmi_drive=2
```

Save the file and exit back to the terminal

Adding HTTP streaming (Optional)

Edit the mpd configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/mpd.conf
```

Add the following code to the end of the file and save

```
    audio_output {
    type            "httpd"
    name            "My HTTP Stream"
    encoder         "lame"
    port            "8000"
    quality         "5.0"
    # bitrate         "128"
    format          "44100:16:1"
    }
```

Issues Resolved

I found that when I played sounds with MPD that the sound was played twice with a slight delay between the two outputs. The only way I could stop this was by disabling the 'ALSA' section in the MPD configuration file

Edit the mpd configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/mpd.conf
```

Find the following section of code

```
    # An example of an ALSA output:
    #
    audio_output {
    type            "alsa"
    name            "My ALSA Device"
    device          "hw:0,0"        # optional
    format          "44100:16:2"    # optional
    mixer_device    "default"       # optional
    mixer_control   "PCM"           # optional
    mixer_index     "0"             # optional
    }
    #
```

Now comment out this section as shown below

```
    #audio_output {
    #       type            "alsa"
    #       name            "My ALSA Device"
    #       device          "hw:0,0"        
    #       format          "44100:16:2"    
    #       mixer_device    "default"       
    #       mixer_control   "PCM"           
    #       mixer_index     "0"             
    #}
```

Save, and exit back to the terminal

If you have not already done so now would be a good time to copy some MP3 files to the `music_directory` specified in the 'mpd.conf' file

At this point it is worth rebooting the system

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Remaining Issues

Comment: I think it would be better if you could edit this to be a question about setting up mpd and pulseaudio and then answer it yourself.